# Exclude words with pattern 'xyyx' but include words that start & ends with same letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to match words that starts and ends with the same letter (excluding single characters like 'a', '1' )

`(^.).*\1$`

and another regex to avoid matching any strings with the format 'xyyx' (e.g 'otto', 'trillion', 'xxxx', '-[[-', 'fitting')

`^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)`

How do I construct a single regex to meet both of the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the pattern with the negative lookahead followed by the pattern for the match. But note to change the backreference to `\3` for the last pattern as the lookahead already uses group 1 and group 2.

Note that the `.` also matches a space, so if you don't want to match spaces you can use `\S` to match non whitespace chars instead.

```
^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)(.).*\3$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/li9OT8/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have an additional question - Suppose we want to include words that start and end with the same character AND have the format 'xyyx'. This can be done by replacing the negative lookahead to a positive lookahead right? i.e `^(?=.*(.)(.)\2\1)(.).*\3$`

Comment: @Naja That is correct, see https://regex101.com/r/bM9dnE/1

Answer (score 0):

I would place the negative look-ahead *after* the initial character, and let it exclude the final character (as those two should be part of a **positive** capture):

[`^(.)(?!.*(.)\2.).*\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/uAx9RN/1)

Note that the negative check concerns characters *between* the start and ending character, and so these words would not be rejected:

```
oopso
livewell
```